# Lv not showing correct in fdisk

Tags: 12.04, lvm, fdisk

I am working on a project with iscsi to create a iscsi-target and initiator. Right now i made a logical volume which looks like this:

[image]

But when I do fdisk -l it shows:

[image]

The problem is why does it make a (-) between vg0 and sysadmin19, and where did mapper came from ?

Hope someone can help me. I am going to make the logical volume accessible from the initiator.